How to abort langchain chat memory
I have a langchain chat memory demo, I want to interrupt during the generation process， this is demo code.
const model = new ChatOpenAI({streaming: true});

const prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.fromMessages([
  [
    "system",
    "You are a helpful assistant. Answer all questions to the best of your ability.",
  ],
  new MessagesPlaceholder("chat_history"),
  ["human", "{input}"],
]);

const chain = prompt.pipe(model).pipe(new StringOutputParser());

const chainWithHistory = new RunnableWithMessageHistory();

const res1 = await chainWithHistory.invoke(
  {
    input: "Hi! I'm MJDeligan.",
  },
  { configurable: { sessionId: "langchain-test-session" } }
);

I give chat model bind a signle, but it don't work
chat.bind({ signal: controller.signal })

